# Mysql query for booking car and driver for given interval of time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have mysql table having 4 column- Driver, startdate, Enddate, car.
Now i need to write query to book driver, if driver and car free at particular time(between starttime and endtime) then book driver and car. **If driver free but car not free ( book by other) also not book 
the driver(means booking fail) because car not available.**

i am try like this but not get correct answer.

```
select * from driver 
where DiverName=? 
and Car=? between StartDateTime=? and EndDateTime=?

select StartDateTime='2014-11-28 12:59:00'  and EndDateTime=' 2014-12-31 13:59:00 ' 
from driver 
where DriverName='rohit' or CarDetails='discover'
```

these are wrong I now , but give me correct one query plz.
**always remember we need both car and driver free in between time interval**

Comment: where do you define whether they are free or not?

Comment: How can i find out if the driver and car is free? Simply by not having a record in the table in that time?

Comment: Is there any default datetime given through which you can find whether it falls between given StartDateTime and EndDateTime of the table?

Comment: please add more details more details to your question

Answer (score 0):

Lets declare the time you want to find out if the driver and car is free :

```
  Declare @time datetime
    Set @time = '2014-11-28 12:59:00'
```

Then you can find out if there is a free driver and car by using this:

```
select * from driver
where @time not between StartDateTime and EndDateTime
```

This will show you, if there are cars and drivers that are free for your specific time.